# Creating a Window in PowerShell using WPF

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml

I just start to understand slowly PowerShell, where I ended up with a problem to present a summary in a window. Someone suggested using WPF.

Using WPF for the first time, I found some examples, I did use to experiment like the example below.

```
Clear-Host

#Build the GUI

[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Name="Window" Title="Test Writing Results" WindowStartupLocation = "CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize"
Width = "1000" Height = "1000" ShowInTaskbar = "True" Background = "white"> 
<StackPanel >
    <TextBlock x:Name = 'textblock' TextAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock.Inlines>
        <LineBreak />
            <Run FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="36" Text="!!! Test Results !!!">
            <Run.Foreground>
                <LinearGradientBrush>
                        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="0.25" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.75" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>    
                </Run.Foreground>    
               </Run>
         </TextBlock.Inlines>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping = "Wrap">
         <LineBreak />
            $b
         <LineBreak />
    <Run FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="16" Foreground="Blue" Text="     Question Nr:          Question Asked                              Your Answer" />
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
"@

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )

#Connect to Controls
$textblock = $Window.FindName('textblock')
```

I then tried to add some code to create a table. I found a nice example here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-define-a-table-with-xaml

To my disappointment, I can't just copy this in-between lines and ended up with all kinds of error messages. I assume, the first issue is, that I need to add the correct assembly and also, not sure what else is needed?

I only need a simple window with some text followed by a table.

Can someone help, how I can do that?

Comment: Do you have to use a table or can you use another object? I think if you want to use objects that are more advanced, you should switch to using C#. A screenshot or example of what you are going for would be great :)

Comment: Well, I also can use another object. Trying to make a long personal project short. I built a vocabulary trainer with a test section and at the end would like to show up results. I would be happy, to be able to show something like the link at the end. Most important to me, to be able to use a 'table' and to have colored fonts, which I am not able to do in a listview in PowerShell itself.
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/media/how-to-define-a-table-with-xaml/planetary-information-xaml-table.png)

Comment: I think you've run into one of the issues of using PowerShell to the backend to a WPF form. It's quite limited in what it can do. I would recommend looking into a `datagrid` as it allows headers, rows and columns

Comment: Hello I.T Delinquent, thanx a lot for the answer. Am I able to use different colors on each line on a datagrid? What I have seen so far, was presented in a very simple and boring form, therefore my wish, to use WPF. If I would be able to use the code in my link in the comment before and be able to run it through PowerShell, that would help already. Maybe there is a way?